# How to force a compile error in C?? When for example passing an integer to printf when %s is a format specifier

Tags: c, clang, printf

I am building my own version of the printf function in C and I need to replicate the original's behavior. I am trying to throw a compile error in a situation like the one written below:

```
// printf("%s %s", 3, 2);
```

How can I force a compile error when the code below gets executed?
I wanted to display the following error:
`format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'int'`

Comment: You write a compiler or you simply use an existing compiler's treat-all-warnings-as-errors option.

Comment: There might be compiler extensions that allow providing some attribute that marks a function to use `printf` like semantics. Naming the compiler might help a lot.

Comment: Those compilers that emit diagnostics specific to the characteristics of particular library functions are able to do so because they contain code for those particular special cases.  Standard C does not provide any way for your code to request such behavior from the compiler.

Comment: Note that MS Visual C will *warn* about `printf` at *compile* time but at runtime it detects a `NULL` pointer and helpfully outputs "(null)" instead of dereferencing it. You can imitiate this run-time behaviour. But you are asking that the compiler verifies the arguments against a format string in a function it knows nothing about. How do you expect the compiler to know that your `%s` in a string literal means the same as in the library functions? Anyway, it's not an error, but a warning which the compiler gives as a courtesy. It is not required by the C standard.

Comment: `gcc` provides the [`format` attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.3.0/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes).  As does [`clang`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#format).

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can I guarantee type safety of variadic arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295651/how-can-i-guarantee-type-safety-of-variadic-arguments)